# How to return an object of type "Object" without causing a type mismatch

Tags: java

How can I return type `Object` from a method to an unknown type without causing a type mismatch?

Comment: What do you mean by "causing type mismatch"? Can you post some sample code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: If he has a method declared to return an `Object`, the mismatch presumably occurs when he tries to store the result of the method-call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Generics to infer the return type, like this:

```
public <T> T methodX() {
  return (T) someValue; //Note that you should ensure that this cast succeeds or catch the possible ClassCastException here
}

//call it like this:
String s = methodX();
```

Note that you need to ensure you can cast to inferred type, so you might want to pass `Class<T>` as a parameter, in order to check the type of `T`.

Inferring the type of `T` just from the assignment might be helpful if you're actually returning a generic object whose generic parameter is `T`. Have a look at `Collections.emptyList()` for example, which returns an empty `List<T>` (so there aren't any elements in the list that are not of type `T`).

You could also set bounds for the `T` type:

```
public <T extends Number> T methodX() {
  return (T) someValue;
}

//would compile
Integer i = methodX();

//this would not compile, since s is not a number
String s = methodX();
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a type mismatch if you for instance try to do something like `String str = new Object()`.

If you know that the method returns, say a `String`, i.e., if it looks like

```
public Object yourMethod() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

then you can cast the result on the call-side, like this:

```
String result = (String) yourMethod();
```

(If `yourMethod` does *not* actually return a `String`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`!)

---

If you have a method declared as

```
public String yourMethod() {
    ...
}
```

then you *can't* return an `Object`, you'll have to return a `String`.

Comment: I'm using generics so I don't know what type I am returning. Is there a way to return type Object to the original type?